# storing the highest game score in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a simple game in browser without using any backend. Is there a way for me to store the highest score in the browser using only javascript or react?

Comment: You can localStorage or sessionStorage

Comment: can I do it both in react and javascript? Which would work better?

Comment: Javascript Indeed, It provide same thing as react but in less lines of code it can be done

Answer (score 2):

Yes , of course . You can use localStorage , this will alow you to store any information in the browser and fetch it later.

**Example :**

```
let score = 0;
score = 50;
localStorage.setItem('currentScore', score);

// And if you want to get the score

let getCureentScore = localStorage.getItem('score');

// do something with getCurrentScore
```

Hope this could helps you :)

Comment: thank you so much for your response. Do you know what could be easier/better? React / vanilla js? Thank you for your patience, I am new to this!

Comment: In react or js app you can use it like in the example above , but if you want to do something else , maybe in react they have some additional packages.